# How to keep double quotes in variables in shell

Tags: shell

I use jq to process json str, but the shell does not retain double quotes. I can't add an escape character because the json str is externally sent.I want to keep the double quotes of the original string。

The json string is dynamically generated, the data content is undefined, I can't use `sed` to add double quotes

```sh
# The json_str is externally sent. 
# Assume that the content is "{"name": "John", "age": 0}"
# I want get the name

echo "$json_str" | jq -r ".name"
```

I expect the output is "John", but the actual output is

```
parse error: Invalid literal at line 1, column 6
```

Comment: the `json_str`  is externally sent, I can't add an escape

Comment: ok, I  will modify my question

Comment: Where you write `Assume that the content is "{"name": "John", "age": 0}"`, do you mean the outer quotes are part of the content?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use single quotes

```
json_str='{"name", "John", "age": 22}'
```

or escape the double quotes

```
json_str="{\"name\", \"John\", \"age\": 22}"
```

Comment: the json_str is externally sent, I can't add an escape. My question is confusing, so I just modified it. sorry

Comment: Well, it cant be escaped from the source, but it doesnt matter you cant work with afterwards, but the most simply is probably to replace closing quotes of variable by single quotes and problem should be solved

Answer (score 2):

*Note that this answer applies to the original version of the question.*

> I expect the output is "John"

Apart from the error introduced by your test case, the use of option `-r` is the issue:

```
   ·   --raw-output / -r:

       With  this  option, if the filter´s result is a string then it will
       be written directly to standard output rather than being  formatted
       as a JSON string with quotes.
```

If you don't want colored output, you can use `-M` instead:

```
   ·   --colour-output / -C and --monochrome-output / -M:

       By  default,  jq outputs colored JSON if writing to a terminal. You
       can force it to produce color even if writing to a pipe or  a  file
       using -C, and disable color with -M.
```

Answer (score 0):

The quote in the JSON example are part of the JSON layout, not the content of the files.
When you want to have the quotes, you can use

```
echo "${json_str}" | jq -r ".name" | sed 's/.*/"&"/'
```

or

```
name=$(echo "${json_str}" | jq -r ".name" | sed 's/.*/"&"/')
```